# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as' in sql server

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have the following query whenever I run it, it gives me incorrect syntax near 'As'

```
select 
    count(id_cat) as catcnt,
    id_cat, ccatname, ccatpermalink,
    (select ccatname 
     from btnn_classifiedcategory 
     where syncoperation <>'D' and id_ccat = id_cat) as catname 
from 
    btnn_myclassifides
where 
    syncoperation <> 'D' 
    and Expirydate >= cast(convert(varchar(100), getdate(), 101) as datetime)
    and id_cat in (select id_ccat 
                   from BTNN_ClassifiedCategory 
                   where syncoperation <> 'D' and id_ccat = bcc.id_ccat) as cnt 
                    from BTNN_ClassifiedCategory bcc
```

It is my query please help me

Answer (score 1):

That last part of your query doesn't work out at all:

```
    and id_cat in (select id_ccat 
                   from BTNN_ClassifiedCategory 
                   where syncoperation <> 'D' and id_ccat = bcc.id_ccat) as cnt 
                    from BTNN_ClassifiedCategory bcc
```

There shouldn't be an `as cnt` after this subselect, and that extra `from BTNN_ClassifiedCategory bcc` doesn't fit in anywhere at all......

Does this query work:

```
select 
    count(id_cat) as catcnt,
    id_cat, ccatname, ccatpermalink,
    (select ccatname 
     from btnn_classifiedcategory 
     where syncoperation <>'D' and id_ccat = id_cat) as catname 
from 
    btnn_myclassifides
where 
    syncoperation <> 'D' 
    and Expirydate >= cast(convert(varchar(100), getdate(), 101) as datetime)
    and id_cat in (select id_ccat 
                   from BTNN_ClassifiedCategory AS bcc
                   where syncoperation <> 'D' and id_ccat = bcc.id_ccat)
```

Comment: it giving now The multi-part identifier "bcc.id_ccat" could not be bound,Invalid column name 'ccatname', and Invalid column name 'ccatpermalink'. error marc

Comment: @Aties: updated my response - does it work now?? Your whole query is pretty messy .... to make sure you're selecting the proper things, you should have **proper table aliases** for all tables involved... I'm just guessing here, since I don't know your table structure and what you're really trying to do...

Comment: @Aties: well then go through your query very carefully, add table aliases, and define which column comes from which table. Right now, it's not clear at all. Doing so you'll certainly find out where something is going wrong (e.g. a column is not from the right table or something like that)

Answer (score 0):

You need not the last  `as cnt` and the last `from BTNN_ClassifiedCategory bcc`

And may be better if you assure the 1st subquery return only 1 row as:

```
(select top 1 ccatname 
     from btnn_classifiedcategory 
     where syncoperation <>'D' and id_ccat = id_cat) as catname
```